# Dynamic landing page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

How can I render two different landing pages conditionally? For example, if the user has been enrolled in some classes, show him the page class list. If not, show the add class page as landing page. I just want to learn the idea, the example was just a use case.

Comment: Use the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) service. 
For more information see [Developer Guide: Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score 0):

show code:

3 options
if elements are on the same page:
ng-if
ng-show

if they are two different html pages. 
you can do it in your router. Ng-route / UI-Router

javascript can do window.open / document.location

use angularjs $location services.